# When is a function registered with atexit() called

Tags: c++, destructor, atexit

I want to know if functions registered with `atexit()` are called before or after global variables are destroyed. Is this specified by the standard or implementation defined?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is well-defined, and depends on whether the object in question was constructed before or after the function got registered using `atexit()`:

> **3.6.3 Termination**
>
> **3.** If the completion of the initialization of an object with static storage duration is sequenced before a call to `std::atexit` (see `<cstdlib>`, 18.5), the call to the function passed to `std::atexit` is sequenced before the call to the destructor for the object. If a call to `std::atexit` is sequenced before the completion of the initialization of an object with static storage duration, the call to the destructor for the object is sequenced before the call to the function passed to `std::atexit`. If a call to `std::atexit` is sequenced before another call to `std::atexit`, the call to the function passed to the second `std::atexit` call is sequenced before the call to the function passed to the ﬁrst `std::atexit` call.

My layman's interpretation of the above is that stuff that got constructed *before* you called `atexit(handler)` gets destroyed *after* `handler()` is called, and vice versa. I am sure there are subtleties, but this seems to be the basic principle.

Comment: Basically, yes.  The wording in the Standard is more complicated because in a multithreaded program, "before" and "after" have tricky definitions and don't always act like you'd expect.

Comment: With a note that `constructed` means *the constructor ended* and that we only consider complete objects, not bases or attributes.